# Push to arrays into madrill JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mandrill

**I have a form which has the fields recipient and email. The user has the option to add more recipients.**

```
<div class=" form-inline">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Recipients</label>
    <script>
        var counter = 1;
var limit = 50;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML =  "<br>  <input  class='form-control reciptest' placeholder='Recipient Name' type='text'> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<input  class='form-control emailtest' placeholder='Recipient Email' type='text'>"
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
    </script>
    <div id="dynamicInput">
  <input  class='form-control reciptest' placeholder='Recipient Name'  type='text'> <input type="text" class="form-control emailtest" placeholder="Recipient Email">
    <br>
       </div>
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse" value="Add Another Email" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

  </div>
```

**Inside the email processing function the inputs of the two classes are split into an array like this**

```
var emails = document.getElementsByClassName( 'emailtest' ),
    email  = [].map.call(emails, function( email ) {
        return email.value;
    }).join( ',' );

var names = document.getElementsByClassName( 'reciptest' ),
    rname  = [].map.call(names, function( rname ) {
        return rname.value;
    }).join( ',' );
```

**Here is where my problem lies**

This code currently works to push the emails into the array,but I am unable to add the recipients email into the array

```
var to =[]; 
email.split(',').forEach(function(k){ to.push ( {email:k, type:'to'});     
rname.split(',').forEach(function(r){ to.push ( {email:k, type:'to', name:'r'});
```

**How do i go about merging these two arrays and keeping them in the order it was entered ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you seem to try to merge both emails and recipient names in to the array `to`. So, you may try this:

```
var to =[]; 
var emails = email.split(',');
var rnames = rname.split(',');
emails.forEach(function(em,i){
    var recipient = {email: em, type: 'to', name: null};
    if (rnames.length>i)
        recipient.name = rnames[i];

    to.push(recipient);
});
```

Comment: Yes i am trying to get it into one array like { email: email 1, type:'to', name: name1 } and then push it into the var to []

Comment: I need the names to go into the key value name:null

Comment: As you see from the code, `rnames[i]` is updated to `recipient.name`. The resultant `to` contains all information you want. `null` is just a fallback to support the case where you have insufficient recipient names to fill.

Comment: Thanks. This works until i try to display the var name in my email template. Every email receives all the users names